# Access a specific index of Ember.ArrayProxy in Handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I have this code in my handlebars template:

```
  {{#each maps as |map|}}
    {{map.title}}
  {{/each}}
```

Which gives me the title of every map.

But if I try to access a specific index, like this:

```
<p>{{maps.[0].title}}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{{maps.Get.[0].title}}</p>
```

It gives me nothing (but it compiles).

the 'maps' variable is of type:

> Ember.ArrayProxy

So how can I access the map located at index 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three good options:

1. Use the [`firstObject` property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#property_firstObject):

   ```
   <p>{{maps.firstObject}}</p>
   ```
2. Use the [`get` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get):

   ```
   <p>{{get maps '0'}}</p>
   ```
3. Use a computed property in your controller:

   ```
   firstMap: Ember.computed('maps.[]', function() {
       return this.get('maps')[0];
   })
   ```

Notice that the second two allow you to choose *any* item in the array, not just the first.

Comment: Ah I tried maps.get('firstObject') which was not compiling.
Weird that I didn't find this in the guides, where can I find this information (so that I don't need to ask this simple questions in the future)?

Comment: The first one can be found in the documentation for `ArrayProxy`. The API guides are sometimes a pain, but they often have very useful information (you just have to sift through them to see if they have what you want). The third one is just a standard Ember computed property which you should have learned about fairly early on. The second one (the most versatile), can't be found in the guides anywhere unfortunately. Maybe that's something that I'll submit a PR to correct.